# IIS is not starting up since about 2 weeks ago

Tags: iis

I don't know what's caused this, but IIS will not start up for about 2 weeks now. Anyone else had this problem?

There doesn't seem to be any event logs for it either, so really hard to diagnose what the issue is?

Other developers with the same updates say it's working for them so i don't feel like rolling back an update will resolve anything.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://forums.iis.net/t/1183365.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to right click on iis and go to properties, then set the RUN property to maximize window. It must have been stuck on another window or something.

[image]